# ColdFusion 11 IIS Connector ExecuteAppCmd.exe side-by-side config is incorrect

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-7, coldfusion-11

I have a clean developer install of ColdFusion 11 and IIS on Windows 2008 Server R2. When I run the wsconfig.exe (as admin), then I click "Add" I get the following in the console output:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\ADMINI~1.CFW\AppData\Local\Tem
p\2\\ExecuteAppCmd\ExecuteAppCmd.exe": CreateProcess error=14001, The applicatio
n has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Pleas
e see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for mo
re detail
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at com.adobe.coldfusion.connector.connectorinstaller.IISWebSites.getWebS
ites(IISWebSites.java:289)
        at com.adobe.coldfusion.connector.connectorinstaller.IISWebSites.scanMet
abase(IISWebSites.java:66)
        at com.adobe.coldfusion.connector.connectorinstaller.IISWebSites.<init>(
IISWebSites.java:51)
        at com.adobe.coldfusion.connector.connectorinstaller.gui.AddConfigDialog
.getWebServerPanel(AddConfigDialog.java:269)
        at com.adobe.coldfusion.connector.connectorinstaller.gui.AddConfigDialog
.initDialog(AddConfigDialog.java:158)
        at com.adobe.coldfusion.connector.connectorinstaller.gui.AddConfigDialog
.<init>(AddConfigDialog.java:92)
        at com.adobe.coldfusion.connector.connectorinstaller.gui.ConfigFrame$2.a
ctionPerformed(ConfigFrame.java:297)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=14001, The application has f
ailed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see t
he application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more deta
il
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 46 more
```

IIS had these features installed:

- Static Content
- Default Document
- HTTP Errors
- ASP.NET
- .NET Extensibility
- CGI
- ISAPI Extensions
- ISAPI Filters
- HTTP Logging
- Windows Authentication
- Request Filtering
- IP and Domain Restrictions
- IIS Management Tools

My initial approach was to use the ColdFusion 11 Lockdown Guide step-by-step for install. I got to the "Run the ColdFusion Web Server Configuration Tool" section before I realized the issue.

After a looking through all my security settings and changing some service login's, I uninstalled ColdFusion (64 bit) and IIS then restarted. I then reinstalled CF11 Development Version using the secure profile and IIS. The web server option I used upon install was to use the built-in server. No further lockdown was done. Same issue.

The ColdFusion Administrator does load on the browser.

The following MS VC++'s are installed:

- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable - x86 11.0.61030
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable - x64 11.0.61030

I'm not sure what's off here, any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Is that the Update 4 build number for VC++ 2012? If not, apply Update 4.

Comment: It is, I just reinstalled update 4 to make sure and the version # didn't change.

Comment: Is there any more info in the "application event log" as the error states? Can also try and _repair_ the Microsoft Visual C++ installation - [Message: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect](http://www.chiefarchitect.com/support/article/KB-01046/)

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Windows... we'll see where that takes me and if it still happens I'll look at that. Thanks Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris said, the answer is to make sure you have the correct "bitness" for the MS VC++ redistributable package. The proper download for that package can be found at this [link from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092), and a further explanation may be found on my blog at this [link](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2014/10/23/Sidebyside-Configuration-Error-installing-CF-11-on-Win2008r2).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a bug post:

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3761543

Since the ColdFusion install is 64-bit it needs a MS C++ 2008 x64 SP1 Redistributable package installed. The ColdFusion install only installs the 32-bit version of 2008.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092

Once I got that installed, it worked.